# AngularJS Get fails to retrieve image url with "302 found"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to add an image to my AngularJS app with a url received from a random cat image site.
this is my controller.js:

```
'use strict';

 /* Controllers */
 var catPath = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&results_per_page=1";
 var Controllers = angular.module('museum1.controllers', []);
 Controllers.controller('oneCatController', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(catPath).success(function(data) {
        $scope.imgurl = data;
        console.log($scope.imgurl);
    });
 }]);
```

and this is the partial that should show the image:

```
<div>

    <img ng-src="{{imgurl}}">
</div>
```

the controller is called by the app.js, not shown here.

Using fireBug I get a message with the path i requested and "302 Found 770ms".
The same path works from the browser address line, and the angular code worked for me using [this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things..

1. Usually I don't use double curly brackets for ng properties.  You may consider removing them.
2. The case sensitivity of your controllers variable is different than that of the variable you access in ng-src.  This may cause the ng-src value to not show up.

In the controller:

```
$scope.imgurl = data;
```

In the HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

Change your HTML to:

```
<img ng-src="{{imageurl}}">
```

Essentially, putting the 'U' into lowercase.

And finally, I'm not sure how the ng-src works off the top of my head.  But, if it uses JavaScript to load the image--and your domain is not the same domain as the image you are loading, then you may be running into cross domain security issues.  But, if ng-src does not use JavaScript to load the image somehow, then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the naming error but I get the same result. 
with regards to your first comment, could you please explain it? I was under the impression that the double brackets are essential for the browser to recognize the data as ng

Comment: @Kepedizer Curly Brackets are used to recognize the data not in an ng-attribute.  They are not needed in the attribute.

Comment: when i remove the brackets i get a:
404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/app/imgurl"

Comment: Weird... Can you provide Plunker?

Comment: @Kepedizer Plunker is designed for editing code on the fly and sharing the modified sample.  To my knowledge GitHub does not offer that.

Comment: Yes.  If you want more assistance, please go to the home page, http://plnkr.co/ , click "launch the editor" and create a sample demonstrating your problem.  Then come back and share the link with us.

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify, following your advice I DID open a plunker account and took my code there... didn't help tho.

Comment: @Kepedizer Well, you need to get the public link to the Plunker so you can share it with us.  I see nothing in your profile link.

Comment: made it public now :)

Comment: This works: http://plnkr.co/edit/rIjquFhff9BxNtxVabPs?p=preview . I don't think you need to use an HTTP get to retrieve an image.  The results will be the binary results of the image.

Comment: 10x for your patience,
so is $http necessary only if I want to receive a json\xml result?

Comment: That is the most common use case.  Technically it can return anything, but I think you were trying to use the 'image data' as if it were a string; which is probably why you had the problem.